# Inserting dynamic data to jstree container

Tags: jquery, jstree

I want to insert dynamic data into my div container that works as jstree. However, I get no style or whatsoever.

```
html = '<ul><li>Root node 1<ul><li id="child_node_1">Child node 1</li><li>Child node 2</li></ul></li><li>Root node 2</li></ul>';
$('#div_tree_content').html(html);
$('#div_tree_content').jstree('refresh');
```

Just to say that I already initialized the div as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#div_tree_content').jstree();

}
```

In the refresh I get an error:

```
TypeError: this.get_container_ul(...)[0] is undefined
```

Comment: Dynamic from what kind of source?, can you provide a sample fiddle with your approach?

Comment: @Hackerman I changed a bit the example.

Comment: Have you tried `$('#treeContainer').jstree(true).refresh();` after injecting the HTML?? I don't know if that would work, but it might.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how jstree works - you can not swap the HTML in the container and expect it to work. You must either use `delete_node`, `create_node`, `rename_node` to modify the structure or recreate the tree with your new data (if it is HTML you need to destroy the current instance first, add the new HTML and recreate the instance).

There are more advanced ways to swap out the data too - like setting `core.data` to a function, but I doubt you need that.

So building on your example:

```
var html = '...';
$('#div_tree_content').jstree(true).destroy();
$('#div_tree_content').html(html);
$('#div_tree_content').jstree();
```